# How to get the  'current' navigation controller from tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Is there is a method to retrieve tab bar controller's current visible navigation controller?

For example, I have 2 tabbars in my program (one navigation controller each) as below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{   
   //Method is called when user clicks on a hyperlink in one of view controllers
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSString *userID = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *navconTitle = [dict objectForKey:@"navcon"];


    //intention is to push a view controller onto the CURRENT navigation stack
    [navcon pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];

    }
}

return YES;
}
```

Can anyone advise me how I can determine the current navigation controller so that I can push more viewcontrollers onto it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use the [`UITabBarController`s](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) selectedViewController property.

```
navcon = (UINavigationController*)myTabBarController.selectedViewController;
[navcon pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

Updating Starsky's Swift answer to iOS 13 ("'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0")

```
guard let tabBarVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return }
    if let currentNavController = tabBarVC.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `UITabBarController selectedViewController` property should be what you are looking for.

So, from a UITabBarController method :-

```
 [self.selectedViewController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

A Swift version, in case someone can't read Objective-C, with an additional solution for how to find the tabBar from anywhere. I use this to push to a screen when processing a notification.

```
guard let tabBarVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return }

if let currentNavController = tabBarVC.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
    currentNavController.pushViewController(someVC, animated: true)
}
```